# I am trying to parse a csv file I am pulling from the internet. The csv reader in python is separating each character into a list element

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file I am pulling from the internet. The csv reader in python is separating each character into a list element.

r.text is a csv file that is properly formatted correctly

```
   r = requests.get('http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=USLV&a=0&b=1&c=2012&d=8&e=30&f=2016&g=m&ignore=.csv')

   csv_f = csv.reader(r.text, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')
   for row in csv_f:
      print (row)
```

How do I parse this file correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Well whats the output and your expected output?

Comment: Rather than using the CSV reader, you could just read each line and split it at every comma

Comment: @Samadi - That is not always a good idea when there exists text qualifiers in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a multi-line string to the csv module: it is seen as a list of 1-character lines.

You have to split according to the lines using `str.splitlines()` as follows:

```
csv_f = csv.reader(r.text.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')
for row in csv_f:
    print (row)
```

result:

```
['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
['2016-09-01', '20.66', '25.790001', '20.48', '21.98', '1302000', '21.98']
['2016-08-01', '27.969999', '29.09', '20.00', '20.60', '1314100', '20.60']
['2016-07-01', '23.73', '28.049999', '23.48', '27.49', '2247200', '27.49']
['2016-06-01', '13.74', '22.200001', '13.36', '22.110001', '1536800', '22.110001']
['2016-05-02', '19.370001', '19.379999', '13.70', '13.75', '1015600', '13.75']
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`csv.reader()` expects an iterable that produces lines, but you are passing in *one string*. Iteration over a string produces individual characters.

Pass in lines by splitting your text:

```
csv_f = csv.reader(r.text.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')
```

or pass in a file-like object:

```
from io import StringIO

csv_f = csv.reader(StringIO(r.text), skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calso use a battle tested approach. This worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=USLV&a=0&b=1&c=2012&d=8&e=30&f=2016&g=m&ignore=.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
printer = csv.reader(response)
for row in printer:
    print row
```

Comment: The OP is using Python 3 (otherwise `r.text` would not have worked). You'd have to wrap a `urllib.request.urlopen()` result in a `TextIOWrapper` in Python  3.